# Printing the shortest path with BFS

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search, maze

I am creating a maze solver which uses `Breadth First Search` algorithm and I'm wondering if I can somehow print the path on the grid instead of just printing the distance value it travelled in order to find the exit. Here is the code down below and thanks in advance.

```
    
    public List<Coords> solve(int x, int y) {
        Queue<Coords> q = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Coords> visited = new ArrayList<>();
        Coords start = new Coords(x,y);
        
        q.add(start);
        visited.add(start);
        
        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
            Coords get = q.poll();
            
            if(maze[get.x][get.y] == 3) {
                System.out.println("found an exit!");
                System.out.println("Distance: " + get.dist);
                break;
            }
            
            if(!visited.contains(get)) {
                visited.add(get);
            }
            
            if(isValid(get.x-1, get.y)) {
                q.add(new Coords(get.x-1, get.y, get.dist+1));
            }
            if(isValid(get.x, get.y-1)) {
                q.add(new Coords(get.x, get.y-1, get.dist+1));
            }
            if(isValid(get.x+1, get.y)) {
                q.add(new Coords(get.x+1, get.y, get.dist+1));
            }
            if(isValid(get.x, get.y+1)) {
                q.add(new Coords(get.x, get.y+1, get.dist+1));
            }
            
            
        }
        return visited;
    }
    
}
```

The output is :
`found an exit! Distance: 20`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question perfectly, but don't you already have this data in your `Queue<Coords> q` object?

If that's the case, then you could have something like this:

```java
if (maze[get.x][get.y] == 3) {
    System.out.println("found an exit!");
    System.out.println("Distance: " + get.dist);
    for(Coords c : q) { 
        System.out.println(c); 
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: I tried but it keeps printing `Coords` objects and it doesn't stop.

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesnt stop"?

Comment: I meant that it didn't stop printing the Coords objects but I've actually managed to find the solution by adding the parent property for every object and it actually prints the path. Thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: glad you found a solution!